# Uncaught exception: -[AccessibilitySettingsController setAXInspectorEnabled:specifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104004800

Tags: earlgrey

I have tried running Earlgrey-test demo with macOS Sierra & Xcode 8,but show me the error as above; in the git issues list, haven't found solution.

Comment: What is the version of EarlGrey that you're using? Are you building it from head?

Comment: i'am using a CocoaPods version from 1.0.1, pod installed EarlGrey version 1.0.0

Comment: Can you try installing 1.4.0? This issue for EarlGrey was already fixed a few releases before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running an outdated version of EarlGrey that doesn't support iOS 10. Please use the [latest release](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/releases) or [HEAD from github](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey)

Comment: i use CocoaPods as the way to get start my project